# Python function execution

Tags: python

So i found this site called codewars.com and wanted to signup. When i selected my language as python, it gave me a problem to solve:

The code does not execute properly. Try to figure out why.

```
def multiply(a, b):
  a * b
```

I am not able to figure out why. It executes correctly in PyCharm using python 3.4 when i added `print(a*b)` instead of a*b and when i called the function using `multiply(2,3)`. The code is also being successfully executed using just the given snippet. It has been given that the above python code is in 2.7 Any ideas?

Comment: Have you consider using return to return the result of a*b?

Comment: Do you want this function to return the value of (a * b)? If so just use `return (a*b)`.

Comment: You need to return something, otherwise the function is void. It should end the function with: return a*b

Comment: I would recommend a Python tutorial to help you learn the basics, for example you may find codecademy.com useful.

Comment: Downvoters: this question shows the problematic code, which is rare on stackoverflow. Sure, it contains a silly mistake, but didn't we all make this sort of mistakes when we started programming?

Comment: I think it's an codewars issue, because "return a*b" doesn't work too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is a function, it needs to return something. Otherwise, running it is kind of useless.

So you probably need to say:

```
def multiply(a, b):
  return a * b
```

You probably want to read more about functions in Python and when this would make sense (passing by reference, for example). This can be a good starting point: [Python functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm).

Comment: Yeah. This solved the problem for me. I was stumped because it said the code was not executing properly. Without the return statement, the code was executing perfectly fine. That was the cause of my confusion.

Comment: @Sibi Exactly. The code is not wrong *per se*. Its error is the fact that it is useless as is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no return value, the code will be OK

```
def multiply(a, b):
   return a * b
```